# bootstrap link turns into a normal button

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

my link doesn't work when I add bootstrap code, it turns into a normal button.this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
     crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="profil.css">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
      echo "<a href='page.php?id={$data["id"]}'class='btn btn-secondary btn-lg disabled' role='button' aria-disabled='true'>Supprimer</a>";
?>   </body></html>
```

it works when removing bootsrap code :

```
echo "<a href='page.php?id={$data["id"]}>Supprimer</a>";
```

or when removing parameters :

```
echo "<a href='page.php'class='btn btn-secondary btn-lg disabled' role='button' aria-disabled='true'>Supprimer</a>";
```

it doesn't remain a link when I combine them.

Comment: Please describe the problem.  What "doesn't work" about the code you're showing us?  How specifically does it fail?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow, could you plz provide more of your code in order to help us identify the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="page.php?id='.$data['id'].'" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg disabled" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Supprimer</a>';
```

Use single quotes and concatenate the php variable inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try onclick and see if it works for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="location.href='page.php?id={$data["id"]}'" type="button" class="btn btn-info">
         www.site.com</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
<a href='page.php?id=<?= $data["id"] ?>'class='btn btn-secondary btn-lg disabled' role='button' aria-disabled='true'>Supprimer</a>
```

Without the <?php opening and echo, just echo the variable.